# Imaginary part of a function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

So, I have the following:

```
Simplify[Im[1/(-1 + Cos[θ])^2], 
 Assumptions -> {θ -> Reals, 0 < θ < π}]
```

which should evaluate to 0, as the function is well-defined, and the variable is real. However the result from this is

```
Im[1/(-1 + Cos[θ])^2]
```

i.e., it cannot be simplified. Any suggestions?

Comment: As John Doty has pointed out, the solution is to use `ComplexExpand`; however, there also are problems with your `Assumptions`. `θ -> Reals` is not the proper syntax to specify that `θ ` is real. It would be `Element[θ, Reals]`. But, since you used an inequality for `θ `, that implies that `θ ` is real and the `Element` statement would be redundant.

Answer (score 5):

A job for the confusingly named `ComplexExpand`:

```
Im[1/(-1 + Cos[\[Theta]])^2] // ComplexExpand
(* 0 *)
```